# Python matplotlib.pyplot: How to make a histogram with bins counts including right bin edge?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

Could you please help me, how to modify the code so to get a histogram with bins counts including right bin edge i.e.  `bins[i-1] < x <= bins[i]` (and no the Left as by default) ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
data = [0,1,2,3,4]
binwidth = 1
plt.hist(data, bins=np.arange(min(data), max(data) + binwidth, binwidth))
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Counts')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there is an option to do it explicitly in either matplotlib or numpy.

However, you may use `np.histogram()` with negative value of your `data` (and bins), then negate the output and plot it with `plt.bar()` function.

```
bins = np.arange(min(data), max(data) + binwidth, binwidth)
hist, binsHist = np.histogram(-data, bins=sorted(-bins))
plt.plot(-binsHist[1:], -hist, np.diff(binHist))
```

Comment: Many many thanks abukaj for the quick answer and especially for the code !

Comment: @Lilly: if you find the answer helpful, you may consider to accept it.

Comment: @ abukaj : sorry I am a new user ... did not know that I have to accept it. Done !